# How to use sshkey with subprocess

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, public-key

I'm trying to connect to a router over ssh and write a command to the shell.
I think the connection works, because I get an empty output and not an error message. I know that I have to use a keyfile to connect really on the device. Maybe that's the reason why the output is empty.

**This is my code:**

```
mykey = os.path.expanduser('C:\\Users\\taaiaal1\\PycharmProjects\\hal_dmms_application\\dev_ssh')
command = 'pcb_cli -u cwmpd pcb://ipc:[/var/run/IGD] -i \'?\''

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", username + '@' + host + ':' + port, command],
                       shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
print(result)
```

Where should I integrate the keyfile?

I feel like checked every page google let me find and even in the subprocess python doc I couldn't find anything. Is this even possible? I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Why dont simply use paramiko instead. http://www.paramiko.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers:

- First of all **port** is not given after `:`, It it given with `-p` option
- If key is required then you have to specify it using `-i` option. Make sure permissions on the key are `0400`.
- You are giving remote command as a list and also giving `shell=True` these are in a way mutually exclusive options. If you want use shell=True then you give command as a single string.
- If want to collect output of a remote command simply use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). It uses popen() function inernally but gives you simpler interface. Don't forget try/except around the function as it raises exception if something went wrong with ssh itself or the remote command's exit status is non-zero.

Your code may look like:

```
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "-i", "<path to your key>", "-p", "<port number>", "{}@{}".format(user, host), command])
    print(out)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    pass
```

Look at my [implementation](https://github.com/rsjethani/remote-exec/blob/master/remote-exec.py) of executing remote commands if you want to see some of the good practices for executing remote commands.

**PS:** There are two different ways of using subprocess functions: one which require a shell to execute your command for eg if the remote command has a wildcard(ls *.txt) OR your remote command does not require the shell for eg executing `uname -a`. Please look at the subprocess documentation link above.

Comment: Yes this is fine. Host part can be an ip address or a hostname like 'myserver'. For latter case the name should either be in your /etc/hosts file or recognized via DNS. I have edited the example in my answer

Comment: I added a proxy an it worked with your advices. Thank you!
Important to know is, that the output comes as binary streams.
To convert i used `output.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the -i flag to specify an identity file. See the [ssh manual under identity_file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

In your example, that would be

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh","-i "+mykey, username + '@' + host + ':' + port, command],
                   shell=True,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

There are also high level SSH libraries available for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-i", "/path/to/key", username + '@' + host + ':' + port, command],
                       shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Popen expects an array of arguments formatted in a certain way.
The easiest way to get a proper arg table is to do it like this:

```
command = "ssh -i my.key user@host"
args = command.split(' ')
ssh = subprocess.Popen(args)
```